# Using UIPageViewController with Multiple Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have the following code to create a UIPageViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.index = 0;

self.pageContainer = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

self.pageContainer.dataSource = self;
[[self.pageContainer view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

DMSignUp1ViewController *first = [[DMSignUp1ViewController alloc] init];
DMSignUp2ViewController *second = [[DMSignUp2ViewController alloc] init];

self.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:first, second, nil];

[self.pageContainer setViewControllers:self.viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:self.pageContainer];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.pageContainer view]];
[self.pageContainer didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(self.index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.index--;
    return [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(self.index == 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.index++;
    return [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.index];
}
```

I have two UIViewControllers: DMSignUp1 and 2 which I create and then place in the viewControllers array.

When I go to run it, I get the following error: 'The number of view controllers provided (2) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested transition'

Which I understand is because I am passing the array to use as the view controller. So how do I set that I want to use the first view controller in the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following method at the end of the ViewController.m file

```
- (DMSignUp1ViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    DMSignUp1ViewController *first= [[DMSignUp1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"APPChildViewController" bundle:nil];
    first.index = index;

    return childViewController;
}
```

And, replace the following code

```
DMSignUp1ViewController *first = [[DMSignUp1ViewController alloc] init];
DMSignUp2ViewController *second = [[DMSignUp2ViewController alloc] init];

self.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:first, second, nil];
```

With

```
APPChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Hope this might help you...

Comment: I ended up doing this but chose to use a UINavigationController anyway. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `UIPageViewController spineLocation` set to anything other than `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid` when you're using `[self.pageContainer setViewControllers:` you can only pass an array with one view controller. The API isn't very clear really with it saying `Controllers`. You then provide the additional `viewControllers` when the `UIPageViewController` requests them through the `dataSource`.

[Link to the spine reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).

Comment: I'm using the scroll animation rather than the page turn which I believe means the spinelocation can't be used. I've gone for a different technique anyway but thanks!